# C++ source highlight in Diff mode

Tags: c++, diff

I'd like to know if Emacs has an option to highlight the portions of C++ source inside .diff files generated by e.g. `git diff HEAD~1` or `git log -p`

Right now I have to rename my .diff file to something like .diff.cpp or just use `M+x cpp-mode` and use regular C++ highlighting which somewhat works. Can I get that in diff mode?